# Python: Get number of years that have passed from date string

Tags: python, string, datetime, time, string-conversion

Given that I start with a string, like `'3/6/2011'` which is month/day/year, and the current day is 3/13/2011 (7 days later), how can I find the number of years that have passed since that time (7/365 = `0.0191780821917808`) in Python?

Note that I want to be able to handle any input date.  Not any format though, you can assume the format above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the `timedelta` by subtracting two `datetime`s, which gives you a lot of cool ways to operate on the time difference.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> before = datetime.datetime.strptime('3/6/2011','%m/%d/%Y')
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(now-before)
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
>>> (now-before).days
7
>>> float((now-before).days)/365
0.019178082191780823
```

---

**EDIT:** Wow, who would've thought there was so much depth to this simple question. Take a look at the answer with the most votes on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436957/pythonic-difference-between-two-dates-in-years). Dealing with leap years is a "hard" problem. (Credit to @kriegar)

Comment: I'd then divide (now-before).days by 365 to get the fractional year.

Comment: aren't leap years are a problem with this solution?

Comment: I'm already going to have some margin of error for my application, so leap years probably aren't all that much of a worry, since the inaccuracy from this is < 1%.  Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datestring = "3/6/2011"
>>> (datetime.date.today() - datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%m/%d/%Y").date()).days / 365.0
0.019178082191780823
```