# Annual Return vs Annualized Return vs CAGR

Tags: python, pandas

I read on Internet and Stack Overflow different articles on **Annual Return** vs **Annualised Return** vs **CAGR** and I am a bit confused and I do not know if they are a different or same thing.

Here what I need. Suppose I have a growth rate of 10% over 3 years. Starting with 100$ I have:

Initial capital: 100$
Year 1: 110$
Year 2: 121$
Year 3: 133$

Now the **Annual return** here is 10% and **Annual mean return** should be 33/3=11%. Correct? Obviously, the **Annual mean return** does not give me a good measure of growth rate because does not take into account the compound interest. Am I correct?

Suppose now I reverse my input date in the problem. I have the initial capital 100$ and final 133$ and I want to calculate the growth rate. The formula should be (Capital final/Capital initial)^(1/3)-1.

(133/100)^(1/3)-1=(1,33)^(1/3)=0.098

that correspond more or less to 10%. Are my computation and reasoning correct so far? If so, what is the difference between **Annual Return** vs **CAGR**? It seems they are the same, correct?

Suppose now my time frame goes from September 10 2008 to Ferbuary 10 2012, my time frame is 3 years and 132 days. According to this website (see video) https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/071014/what-formula-calculating-compound-annual-growth-rate-cagr-excel.asp the number of years here is (3 + K) where K is the number of days converted in years, in our example K=132/365=0.36 so the number of years N=3+0.36=3.36 and this is the value I should use in the formula. Am I correct?

Now the last doubt is that the website to calculate K suggest to divide the number of days for 360 or 365 but should I consider in my calculation only the number of days the stock market is open (a number more or less equal to 272)?

The last question about python is, suppose I have a panda data frame df, can someone put a snippet of code I can use to calculate the Annual Return and/or CAGR. The code should take into consideration that the time frame could have a number of days more than one year and not perfectly a multiple of one year (like the example above).

I tried to write it but I am not sure I did a good job.

In addition, if my timeframe is less than one year what happens? Should I use Annualized Return? How the code change in this case?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mostly about finance. And it is much too broad, containing multiple different questions.

Comment: My problem is that I have a python program where I am trying to estimate the performance of a single ETF. As you know before writing an algorithm you need to understand concepts first. I read lot of questions with theory before programming here. Why my case is different? As you notice I already did my research on theory first and I asked only for confirmation on few points. But my problem is that I am still unable to convert my understanding on code because I am a beginner programmer in python, especially on pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to comments and some days of work I found detailed answers to my questions. I'll put them here for the benefits of others. I'll divide them in two parts: theory and programming.

**Theory**

According to my example above if I have an investment with 10% annual return and an initial capital of 100$ I have:

Year 1: 110$ 
Year 2: 121$ 
Year 3: 133.1$

The total earning is 33.1$ and it is called **Cumulative Return**. If you divide this earning for the number of years you get the **Average mean return**. It is a good estimation to understand trends but it does not take in consideration the compound interest. To get the real **Annual Return** you should apply this formula (that is derivative from Compound interest formula -- see Wikipedia for details).

**Annual Return (or CAGR)**=(Capital final/Capital initial)^(1/N)-1

Where N is the number of years. If the start date and end date of investment start on January 1st and finish on December 31th N is an integer, otherwise N could be a real number where the decimal part is calculated as 365/number of days.

**Programming**

Initially, since I am a beginner programmer in Python I thought to complex algorithms to calculate returns from my time series. Later, once I understand theory things became more easy. Suppose you have:

- start_time
- end_time
- start_price
- end_price

the cumulative return is an easy formula in python:

```
cum_return_percentage=((end_price/start_price) - 1)*100
```

also the annual return formula is easy to implement:

```
annual_return=(pow((end_price/start_price),(1/number_years))-1)*100
```

the problem is to calculate correctly the number_years as a real value that take into account the remaining days as decimal values. Here the code I am using:

```
diffyears=end_date.year - start_date.year
difference=end_date - start_date.replace(end_date.year)
days_in_year=isleap(end_date.year) and 366 or 365
number_years=diffyears + difference.days/days_in_year
annual_return=(pow((end_price/start_price),(1/number_years))-1)*100
```

To give the credits, this code comes from this discussion:
[Pythonic difference between two dates in years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436957/pythonic-difference-between-two-dates-in-years)

Hope this help other guys having my same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas are correct, but assuming 10% growth you end up at 133.1 NOT at 133.

Then: (133.1/100)^(1/3)-1 = 10%

Comment: Thanks. Do you agree that CAGR is the same of Annual Return? While Annualised return refers to a return of a year extrapolated from a return got in a period of time less than one year?

Comment: Obviously, there is no fixed term for annual return... but in this example I would say yes.

Comment: What about number of days to better calculate K and N in my formula? Should I assume a year of 365, 360 (I don't understand why the website video reports 360) or 272 (the number of days the stock market is open)?

Comment: 360 is used for historical reasons when not everybody had a computer and dividing by 365 is difficult. Moreover, if you assume a month has 30 days its 30*12. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention 
272 makes no sense in this context. I would use 365 => 3.36

If you use 272 it would be to divide the actual trading days in your sample by 272. However, this should equal ~ 3.36 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll appreciate. The theory is clear now, but now I need info on Python the most important part. I am still trying to play with the data frame, list and tuple in order to calculate N in the formula. N=num years + days/365. The problem is to calculate exactly for each year the number of days. It's not easy for a python beginner like me.  I found something on StackOverflow but it does not work.

Comment: @FriedrichFranz for future reference, please avoid answering off-topic questions on this site. There is a finance StackExchange site, and this question belongs there rather than being encouraged here.

Comment: Feel free to deleted it if you think it is the right thing to do. My problem was a programming one. I am a programmer. But I needed to clarify theory first. Probably I could do that on site you suggested. I am sorry for this. Code was easier than expected once understand theory.

Comment: I found this to compute exactly number of years https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436957/pythonic-difference-between-two-dates-in-years that at the end was the hardest part to implement (I am not a Python expert and I have difficulties with dates)

Answer (score 0):

```
# We ask the user for the initial and final amounts of the investment

start_price = float(input('Initial investment amount: '))
end_price = float(input('Final amount of the investment: '))
start_time = input('Investment date: ')    
end_time = input('Final date considered for the CAGR calculation: ')
    
def CAGR(start_price, end_price, start_time, end_time):
    # days number
    fecha1 = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%d")
    fecha2 = datetime.strptime(end_timeal, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dias = (fecha1 - fecha2).days
    años = dias/365
    return (end_price/start_price)**(1/años)-1
CAGR  = CAGR(start_price, end_price, start_time, end_time)

# CAGR is negative in the case of losses.
if start_price > end_price:
    CAGR = -CAGR
print ('Your investment had a CAGR of {:.2%} '.format(CAGR))
```